# How do you hide a column in Excel with AppleScript?

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I've been looking for a way to script through a worksheet and hide particular columns.  When I researched I found "[select column and hide](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=28378)" but I realized that you have to select the column first, manually, when running:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
   set selectedColumn to entire column of cell 1 of selection
   set hidden of selectedColumn to (hidden of selectedColumn)
end tell
```

so to try and select the column through a script I wrote:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set myColumn to range "$A" of sheet 1 of workbook "Workbook1"
    set selectedColumn to entire column of cell myColumn of selection
    set hidden of selectedColumn to (hidden of selectedColumn)
end tell
```

but it throws an error of:

> The object you are trying to access does not exist

further searching I found an email communication from Apple "[Excel: hide multiple columns with AppleScript](https://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2011/Mar/msg00089.html)" but when I try the one liner of:

```
set hidden of (get entire column of (get range "$A")) to true
```

but it also fires:

> The object you are trying to access does not exist

Other researching I found "[I need a "hide" script for Microsoft Excel](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1698680)" appears to only work for cells and not columns.

What am I doing wrong with `range`?  Is there a way to hide a column without keystroke and without identifying the column before or after the selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While one can use *code* to first select a `column` before hiding it, it's not necessary.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* hides the `column` by its *number*:

*Syntax:* `set hidden of column n to true` where `n` is an *integer*, e.g.:

```
set hidden of column 1 to true
```

To do it using a `range`:

```
set hidden of (entire column of (range "A:A")) to true
```

---

The following acts on the `active sheet of active workbook` as is:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set hidden of (entire column of (range "A:A")) to true
end tell
```

It's equivalent to:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set hidden of (entire column of (range "A:A")) of active sheet of active workbook to true
end tell
```

To target a specific `sheet` and `workbook` use the appropriate designators, e.g:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set hidden of (entire column of (range "A:A")) of sheet 1 of workbook 1 to true
end tell
```

Where the *integer value* can be whatever is appropriate, or use the `name` *property* e.g:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set hidden of (entire column of (range "A:A")) of sheet "Sheet1" of workbook "Workbook1" to true
end tell
```

The following hides `columns` `A`, `C` and `E` by `range`:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set hidden of (entire column of (range "A:A, C:C, E:E")) to true
end tell
```

Comment: Ah so I see what's going on.  It was the range has to be start:finish correct?  Think that's where my issue was.  The documentation is limited and didn't mention it.

Comment: @Gʀɪᴍ, You might want to have a look at [Excel 2004 AppleScript Reference](https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/excel-2004-applescript-reference.pdf), even though it's a very old publication nonetheless, I've found some of the information informative, although some of it may no longer be applicable to the latest version of Excel. For `range` reference, have a look a pages 15-17.